# How to enable flag for GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_OFFLINE=true?

Tags: gatsby, contentful

How to enable `GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_OFFLINE=true` in GatsbyJS to access content offline?

The [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-contentful/#offline) suggests to `export GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_OFFLINE=true`.
I have tried adding it in the config but still it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me where to add this export or else if the functionality actually works?

Answer (score 1):

You would use `export …` in your .bashrc or similar. You're exporting a variable declaration from the shell script into your shell session, making it available as an environment variable. This prevents you from having to declare the variable on each invocation of `gatsby [command]`.

You can also use `.env.development` to declare this value (without `export`) and Gatsby will pick it up, or you can use `.env` with the dotenv package configured.

Answer (score 0):

It works, but:

- you have to be actually offline
- `NODE_ENV` is not `production` (a.k.a not `gatsby build`)

[See the implementation here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/68a01e76dab803ef467f5e507bf992b88ee22dd5/packages/gatsby-source-contentful/src/gatsby-node.js#L44)

So I think it's just a convenient flag that'll allow you to develop without an internet connection. I'm not sure what the doc meant by `export ...`, but since they're checking for `process.env.GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_OFFLINE`, you can set it by prepending it to whatever command you run in the terminal (ignore the `$`):

```sh
$ gatsby develop
# GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_OFFLINE is undefined

$ GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_OFFLINE=true gatsby develop
# GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_OFFLINE is true

$ GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_OFFLINE=true gatsby build
# GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_OFFLINE is true, but contenful doesn't care
# because NODE_ENV is always set to `production`
```

When doing so (after turning off your network), you should see this logged out in the console:

> Using Contentful Offline cache ⚠️
>
> Cache may be invalidated if you edit package.json, gatsby-node.js or gatsby-config.js files

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solutions but that didn't worked for me. I had a totally different issue. I have never used `gatsby` before.

So, first, I have installed `gatsby` then I checked the `CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN` in `.env.development`. The access token, it had was same as that of `CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID`.

So, I updated the `CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN` and it worked.

Steps to update the `CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN` from contentful portal are:

1. I navigated to contentful portal. and selected my space from left panel.
2. Navigated to settings -> API Keys
3. Under **Content delivery/preview tokens** options, I have selected the name of key (if you have multiple keys, then match the spaceId)
4. Copy `Content Delivery API - access token` and paste it in your `.env.development` file. save it.
5. then run gatsby develop