# How to set GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_OFFLINE flag when using gatsby-source-contentful

Tags: gatsby, contentful

I am new to gatsby. Last week I faced this problem when running the development server. I tried to run the setting `GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_OFFLINE=true` to see if the site can be served from cache.

Where to add this line in Gatsby?

```
export GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_OFFLINE=true
```

Answer (score 0):

There's already a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54948364/10340970), but since it doesn't have a upvoted or accepted answer, here's a summary. You can do one of the following:

- add it in your `.bashrc` ([coreyward's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54963093/10340970))

> You would use export … in your .bashrc or similar. You're exporting a variable declaration from the shell script into your shell session, making it available as an environment variable. This prevents you from having to declare the variable on each invocation of gatsby [command]

- add it in your `.env.development` without `export` ([coreyward's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54963093/10340970))
- append it in front of each invocation of `gatsby develop` (you can also save it as a script in `package.json`)

```sh
$ GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_OFFLINE=true gatsby develop
```

---

Also please note that this flag only works when these 2 conditions are met:

- you have to be actually disconnected from a network
- `NODE_ENV` is not production (a.k.a not gatsby build)