# How to develop offline, with Gatsby and Contentful?

Tags: gatsby, contentful

I have found a few [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948364/how-to-enable-flag-for-gatsby-contentful-offline-true) on the `GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_OFFLINE` flag.

Unfortunately, even with that flag set to `true`, I am unable to run `gatsby develop` offline.

After running `GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_OFFLINE=true gatsby develop`, it crashes at the *load plugins* stage with the following error message:

> ERROR  UNKNOWN
>
> request to
> https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/3uzkvbjc44lv/environments/master/content_types
> failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cdn.contentful.com (value)
>
> FetchError: request to
> https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/3uzkvbjc44lv/environments/master/content_types
> failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cdn.contentful.   com (value)

Any idea what I can try to enable offline development?